# Should I use "will" or "would" for the future tense if there is a condition?

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, future-tense

> Once you send me your final SOP, I **will place** it in the main document.

Or should it be "would place" in the main document since it is conditional?

Thank you

Comment: I would say that you should use will. Would would be the past tense.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular situation, the correct word is "will". If instead you used the word "would", it would lead onto "but...", for example:

"Once you send me your final SOP, I would place it in the main document, but I cannot access it."

Emphasis would be placed on the word "would" in this case.

Comment: Thank you for responding. This is the first time I have ever used any service as such and am pleasantly surprised. I subscribed to 'Grammarly' online service a week ago for these subtle nuances. It turned out to be a huge disappointment. Not only that the site doesn't make any recommendations for these kind of questions, it does not even correct simple sentences. Today, I submitted an incomplete and a wrong sentence on purpose and it didn't catch the error. Anyway, I am just venting out as feel I wasted money. Nonetheless, thanks again for your help.

Comment: @khizi I understand entirely, I'm glad you're happy here!

Answer (score 1):

> Once you send me your final SOP, I will place it in the main document.

It is not conditional because you *assume* the SOP will be sent. You can make it conditional by using 'if'.  In that case you simply have to match tenses.

1. If you **send** me your final SOP, I **will** place it in the main document.
2. If you **sent** me your final SOP, I **would** place it in the main document.